# Remove duplicate notifications when both iOS Apps installed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I've installed the StackExchange app, along with the StackOverflow-standalone app on my iPhone.
Whenever I receive a notification from StackOverflow, my iPhone actually notifies me twice: once for StackExchange, and once for StackOverflow.
That seems pretty annoying to me. Any chance to not push notifications for StackExchange when it's about StackOverflow and the standalone app is installed?

[Disclaimer: I wasn't sure about whether this is a feature request or a bug report. But since both apps are working as supposed, I figured I'm the one having an issue.]

---

It's been quite a while and even though both apps are up to date, the notification bug still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6 and 1.0.1, respectively, currently in review.

The notifications are designed to fire in only one app based on site of origin.  Unfortunately, the device identifier that we were using to group apps together is sometimes returning different values for the two apps.  The new versions of the app use an identifier system that should work more reliably.

Comment: Hey Brian. I've updated both apps and have just verified that they are on v1.6.6 and 1.0.1. I still get both notifications. Any settings I need to change or anything else I've missed?